# IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursorloader

My app keeps crashing when I reopen it. The problem is with this specific activity, which is a listview populated from an sql database using a separate helper class i wrote.

Im using deprecated cursormanager, not sure how to use cursorloader. Any help on how to make the switch would be very much appreciated. Heres the code for the activity causing the issue.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class ExerciseCategories extends Activity {

private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST+1;
private static final int URL_LOADER = 0;
private CategoryDbAdapter mDbHelper;
private String s;
ListView listview;
private Long mRowId; 
Cursor cursor; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.exercise_categories);
    mDbHelper = new CategoryDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(listview);

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void fillData() {       
    cursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllCategories();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] from = new String[] { CategoryDbAdapter.KEY_CATEGORY };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };
    SimpleCursorAdapter categories = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.category_row, cursor, from, to);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.category_list);
    listview.setAdapter(categories);
    mDbHelper.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case INSERT_ID:
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.promptdialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
        final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                s = userInput.getText().toString();
                                mDbHelper.open();
                                mDbHelper.newCategory(s);
                                fillData(); 
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case DELETE_ID:
            mDbHelper.open(); 
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            mDbHelper.deleteCategory(info.id);
            fillData();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

heres the helper class:

```
public class CategoryDbAdapter {

static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";

private static final String TAG = "CategoriesDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table categories (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "category text not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "categories";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        String[] string = { "Back", "Biceps", "Chest", "Core", "Legs",
                "Shoulder", "Triceps" };
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_CATEGORY, string[i]);
            db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS categories");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public CategoryDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public CategoryDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}

public Cursor fetchAllCategories() {

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
            new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY }, null, null, null,
            null, null);
}

public long newCategory(String category) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public boolean deleteCategory(long rowId) {

    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

public Cursor fetchCategory(long rowId) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor =

    mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,
            new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY }, KEY_ROWID + "="
                    + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

public boolean updateCategory(long rowId, String title) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_CATEGORY, title);
    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

}

Comment: post your DBHelper class

Comment: or add this method  `mDbHelper.open();` into u r `filldata()` function

Comment: do you get the error at this line mDbHelper.deleteCategory(info.id); ???

Comment: adding .open() doesnt change the crashing. the error is not at any specific line. Its at reloading. I think i have to implement onPause and/or onResume but not really sure how

Answer (score 0):

As far as switching to the Loader interface, I personally use, and highly recommend the cwac-loaderex library available here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex

It has a very simple interface and great documentation/code samples.